# Laravel 6 pluck in hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel

**Controller:**

```
$files = File::where('agent_id', $user->id)->with('posts')->get();
```

**Model:**

```
 public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Post', 'id', 'id', 'post_id', 'user_id');
}
```

So this return a bunch of data, for example:

```
{

    "success": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "post_id": 1,
            "transaction_id": 4,
            "agent_id": 2,
            "status": 0,
            "posts": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "john",
                    "email": "john@gmail.com",
                    "phone": "489797878",
                    "type": "1",
                    "verified": 1,
                    "otp": null,
                    "created_at": "2019-11-23 10:17:31",
                    "updated_at": "2019-11-23 10:17:51",
                    "api_token": null,
                    "laravel_through_key": 1
                }
            ]
        }
...
    }
```

What I want is, exclude some data, like `email` or `verified` and etc. I tried `pluck('email')` and also `makeHidden` but no success. any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing some thing like below, ( haven't tested the code but should give you a clue )

```
files = File::where('agent_id', $user->id)
     ->with(['posts' => function ($q) {
         $q->select('name','phone'); // specify whatever you want
      }])->get(['column1','column2']);
```

Comment: Oh great, but what about remove `transaction_id` and `status` ? this just work on child array

Answer (score 1):

Just use `->get()` include list of those you want to get:

**example:**

```
$files = File::where('agent_id', $user->id)->with('posts')->get(['post_id', 'status']);
```